# Is "screen" package still available on linux?

Tags: command-line, package-management, process

Good afternoon everyone, I’m looking to perfect myself right now on linux systems and the course I'm working on talk about **a **command** named "screen"**. However, when trying "`sudo apt-get install screen`" command, no results are found... I searched any similar package with "`apt-cache search screen`" command but nothing matches... On the web, the articles about "screen" command they date from 2013...

Is this package still available ? May I look for other similar command(s) ? If yes, which one ?

My sincere thanks

Comment: Linux is a kernel, so no screen on Linux. However, it is available in the rUbuntu epositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `screen` package is in the Ubuntu repositories for all supported releases of Ubuntu.

- Make sure you are running a currently-supported release of Ubuntu.
- Make sure to run `sudo apt update` to populate your database of available packages. Read your output to ensure the command completed successfully.

```
$ rmadison screen
 screen | 4.0.3-14ubuntu8            | precise          | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 screen | 4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-9 | trusty           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 screen | 4.2.1-2~ubuntu14.04.1      | trusty-backports | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 screen | 4.3.1-2build1              | xenial           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 screen | 4.6.2-1                    | bionic           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 screen | 4.6.2-1ubuntu1             | bionic-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 screen | 4.6.2-3build1              | eoan             | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 screen | 4.8.0-1                    | focal            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 screen | 4.8.0-2                    | groovy           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

Comment: thank you very much !